# scipy.minimize ValueError: The user-provided objective function must return a scalar value

Tags: python, valueerror, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I had read the documentation and tried to understand how to work with `scipy.optimize.minimize()`, but I can not.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(x):
    return x**2

x0 = [-2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]

res = minimize(f, x0)
print(res.x)
```

**Output:** "*ValueError: The user-provided objective function must return a scalar value*."

Comment: What parts of that error message do you have problems with? Your objective function in deed does not return a scalar. For instance, ``f(x0)=[4.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,2.0]``.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve it: x0 should be a number or (1,) array

Answer (score 0):

In your example, your initial array of `x0` is fine. The thing that caused the value error is that the objective function must return a single value, not a list/array of values. You can sum it up or use `l2-norm`.

```
def f(x):
    return sum(x**2)

res = minimize(f, x0)
print(res.x)

[-1.82818467e-08  8.41691947e-08 -1.86620236e-07 -8.41691948e-08
  1.82818469e-08]
```